# PHP PDO not working with select when i am selecting data for 1 week

Tags: php, pdo

//Not working code

```
require ('../catalog/view/theme/default/template/config/dbconfig.php');
$stmt1=$DB_CON->prepare('select count(*) as t,sum(total) as total,CAST(date_added as DATE) as date_added from oc_order where date_added>DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) group by CAST(date_added as DATE) order by date_added DESC');
$stmt1->execute();
$record1=$stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($record1);
```

but above query is working in phpmyadmin and it is returns data properly but it is not working in pdo in php. below code works perfectly even though it is same query

//working code->when i am selecting data for 1 Month

```
$stmt1=$DB_CON->prepare('select count(*) as t,sum(total) as total,CAST(date_added as DATE) as date_added from oc_order where date_added>DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) group by CAST(date_added as DATE) order by date_added DESC');
$stmt1->execute();
$record1=$stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($record1);
```

is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Devon thanks for your response, there is no error in query, i am already handling error

Comment: <?php
$DB_HOST="localhost";
$DB_USER="root";
$DB_PASS="";
$DB_NAME="xyz";
try{
$DB_CON=new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
$DB_CON->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   $e->getMessage();
}
?>

Comment: What is var_dump returning?

Comment: So what is the outcome of that query, that you are saying, that it is not working. No results (empty result set)?

Comment: outcome of query is empty array but same query in phpmyadmin returns a data

Comment: Very strange, it looks fine. Are you sure that you are querying the same db in phpmyadmin and here?

Comment: it is a mistake from my side, sorry i forgot to change my database name previous to new. thanks michaJIS